# Creating page with Mediawiki API by Java

Tags: java, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I'm trying to edit page with APIMediawiki.
But I have token==null and exception :info.bliki.api.UnexpectedAnswerException: Edit token was not obtained.

What I make wrong?

My code:

```
import info.bliki.api.UnexpectedAnswerException;
import info.bliki.api.User;
import info.bliki.api.query.Edit;
import info.bliki.wiki.filter.Encoder;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //MyConnector connection = new MyConnector();
        Connector connection = new Connector();

        User user = new User("myLogin", "myPassword", "http://.../api.php");
        connection.login(user);

        StringBuilder test_page = new StringBuilder();
        test_page.append("== Test page_1 ==");
        test_page.append("Some page text");
        String title = Encoder.encodeTitleToUrl("My_test_page", true);

        Edit newPage = Edit.create().title(title).text(test_page.toString());

        try {
            connection.edit(user, newPage);
        } catch (UnexpectedAnswerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wrong password maybe? wrong url?

Comment: I don't see any `token` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

As svick said, you should probably use a Java library which handles tokens for you. It's a pain to do yourself. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code#Java